# WPF sub-menu overlay rather than expand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sorry I don't really have source code for this as it's more I don't know what element to use.

I'm making a menu navigation control.  The menu will have two levels.  I would like the sub items to show up on the right when a menu item is selected.  However I'd like them to overlay whatever content is there and not just expand.  In the image basically the Sub Item part I would like to display above the red portion.  Right now it will just expand the left menu column area.

I've looked at using a popup control but it seems to have a lot of problems with things like the window moving.  Is it still the best option for something like this?

I've also looked at setting zindex but that seems appropriate only for items in the same control space.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to overlay it? I ask to better understand what is better for your needs.

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml - I want to overlay it because it will only be open temporarily and do not want it causing other items on the screen to resize unnecessarily.  If the user clicks anywhere else when it's open it will just close/hide automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It took me about three day of working to get what i wanted to design.
PopUps are sometime mysterious but they are able to do what do you want.

I think their Key Properties are Placement, HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset.
By setting them in the way you wanted to show, you will see their flexibility.

I have designed my own using ControlTemplates:

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuBackground" Color="#1A1A1A" />

 <!-- Menu: MainMenu Style-->
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="Menu">
     <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource IranSans}"/>
     <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
     <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Menu">
                 <Border Background="{StaticResource MenuBackground}">
                     <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                 </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>

<!-- Fill Brushes -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuBackground" Color="#1A1A1A" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="EnabledForegroundBrush" Color="#CCC" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuClick" Color="#4D4D4D" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemHighlight" Color="#717171" />

<!-- Border Brushes -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!-- Miscellaneous Brushes -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />

<!--SeparatorStyleKey : Menu Separator Styles -->
<!-- [1] Separator Tag -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="Separator">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource MenuClick}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{StaticResource EnabledForegroundBrush}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- TopLevelHeader-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource MenuBackground}">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentPresenter  Margin="6,3,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0 0 3 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="▾" FontSize="13"/>
            </StackPanel>
 <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="2" HorizontalOffset="-8" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
     <Border Padding="8 0 8 8">
         <Border Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{StaticResource MenuClick}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuClick}"  BorderThickness="5">
             <Border.Effect>
                 <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="#AAA" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="10"/>
             </Border.Effect>
             <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
     </Border>
     </Border>
 </Popup>                                   
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ItemHighlight}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource EnabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuClick}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuClick}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- TopLevelItem -->
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource MenuBackground}">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource ItemHighlight}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource EnabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuClick}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- SubmenuItem -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource MenuClick}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Name="Icon" Margin="3,3,9,3" Height="18" Width="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>
            <Border Name="Check" Width="13" Height="13" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="6,0,6,0" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
                <Path Name="CheckMark" Width="7" Height="7"  Visibility="Hidden" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText" Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" Margin="5,2,0,2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsCheckable" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ItemHighlight}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuClick}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Title">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 15 0 10"/>
            <Setter TargetName="InputGestureText" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="HeaderHost" Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource EnabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- SubmenuHeader -->
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource MenuClick}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Name="Icon" Margin="3,3,9,3" Height="18" Width="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>
            <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText" Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"  Margin="5,2,2,2" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="◂" FontSize="13"/>
            <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Right" HorizontalOffset="5" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                <Border Padding="0 8 8 8">
                    <Border Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{StaticResource MenuClick}"  BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuClick}" BorderThickness="5" >
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="#AAA" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="10"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                </Border>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ItemHighlight}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- MenuItem Style -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 4 5 2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8 0 8 0"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 4 5 2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8 0 8 0"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template"
          Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```